# Practical ways to embed a script in a Selenium IDE .side test file?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

In Selenium IDE, I want to create a page via a REST API before commencing some performance tests. I've been using `executeAsyncScript` to do so, but including the entire script, including the embedded page source code (twice escaped), in the `tests.side` JSON file, is becoming somewhat laborious whenever an edit has to be made.

Is there some way of referencing an external file or something?

I still want to do the test setup in Selenium IDE, so please do not suggest using external tools (e.g. a `bash` script containing a `curl` command) on the test environment before running the test suite.

A simplified version of my .side file is included below. What I want to change is the unmanageable nature of the value at `["tests"][0]["commands"][1]["target"]`.

```js
{
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "tests-tests",
  "url": "http://prod:1312",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
    "name": "MakeTestPage",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "instructions/hcf",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "executeAsyncScript",
      "target" : "var data = \"<body><p id=\\\"help\\\">help</p>\\r\\n</body>\" /* et cetera */",
      "targets" : [],
      "value" : ""
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000004",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": []
  }],
  "urls": ["http://prod:1312/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```